# Datagrid with resizable columns background problem

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, background-color

I have a datagrid with a certain background ("#DDD") and a fixed width. The columns must be resizable. My problem is that when I'm using my app and I resize the columns of the datagrid in a way that uses less than all the space available in the datagrid the "unused space background" gets white. It is quite ugly and I would love to have a uniform background. [This is an image of my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Senic.png)

I tried to add a void column with width "*", and it works great until a resize happens

Is there a way to get a desired color also outside the columns?

p.s. I'm also applying a cellStyle from a static resource, dunno if that is the problem.

p.p.s. Here is my code for the grid:

```
<DataGrid         SelectionMode="Extended"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CollectionView}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Background="#DDD"
                  BorderThickness="0"
                  Margin="20,0,20,0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle1}"
                  RowHeaderWidth="0"
                  CanUserAddRows="false"
                  GridLinesVisibility="None"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  MaxWidth="5000" 
                  

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"
                                    Binding="{Binding Id}"
                                    Width="auto"
                                    MinWidth="50"
                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                    SortMemberPath= "OrderId"
                                    SortDirection="Ascending"/>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="80"
                                        Header="Enable"
                                        IsReadOnly="False"
                                        SortMemberPath="OrderEnable">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content=""
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=isSelected, 
      Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                       IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CheckEnabled, 
      Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center">                                    
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Creation Date"
                                    Binding="{Binding CreationDate}"
                                    Width="200"
                                    MinWidth="200"
                                    IsReadOnly="True" 
                                    SortMemberPath="OrderCreationDate"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Modified"
                                    Binding="{Binding Date}"
                                    Width="200"
                                    MinWidth="200"
                                    IsReadOnly="True" 
                                    SortMemberPath="OrderDate"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                    Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                    Width="150"
                                    MinWidth="150"
                                    IsReadOnly="True" 
                                    SortMemberPath="OrderName"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description "
                                    Binding="{Binding Description}"
                                    Width="auto"
                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                    MinWidth="50" 
                                    SortMemberPath="OrderDescription"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header=""
                                    Width="*"
                                    IsReadOnly="True" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

and my code for the cellstyle:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1"
           TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Bottom" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Center" />

        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ToolTip>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Errors}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding 
                                    ErrorHeader.Message}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>

                </ToolTip>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize"
                Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="Height"
                Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background"
                Value="#DDD" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="#DDD" />
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="10,20,10,20" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="#09F" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="White" />
            </Trigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Incompatible}"
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="#80F02020" />
            </DataTrigger>


            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Warning}"
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value ="#80FF5500" />
            </DataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine. Unless you try to narrow down the problem so it's "reproducible" and then "post the relevant source code" here so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, when I copy your code above into a test project, I don't see the white rectangle shown in your image. Your solution of adding an extra `*` column at the end seems to work, even when I start resizing the columns. That said, maybe I'm not resizing the columns in the same way as you are. And besides, that's not the ideal solution.

The white color seems to be coming from the background of the `DataGridRow`s. Adding this style to the `DataGrid` fixes the problem without needed to add an extra column:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#DDD"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```